# Setting variable and string from POST with loop

Tags: php, javascript

Currently I have 100 text input boxes named contact0 through contact101. I am trying to get the Post data and name each string to itself. Meaning `$contact0 = $_POST['contact0'];`all the way up to `$contact101 = $_POST['contact101'];` there has to be a simpler way to set them in a loop or something. Overall the end result is I just want the data entered in the textbox to become the value of the textbox when submitted. Any suggestions will help I might be doing this wrong for the results I want.

```
for ($i = 0; ;$i++){
if($i < 101){
$contact.$i = $_POST['contact'].$i;
echo $contact.$i;
}
else{
break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider amending your HTML form. Rather than create 100 new variables, you can assign all the contacts to an array and then reference them with the array index.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="contacts[]" value="Contact 1 name"/>
<input type="text" name="contacts[]" value="Contact 2 name"/>
// etc...
```

**PHP**

```
$contacts = $_POST['contacts'];
var_dump($contacts);
// prints array(0 => 'Contact 1 Name', 1 => 'Contact 2 Name'...
```

As it now an array, you can reference the contact e.g. `$contacts[34]` and know it will be a valid entry.

**EDIT**

A working example:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['contacts'])) {
        $contacts = $_POST['contacts'];
        echo "<p>The contacts are below:</p>";
        print_r($contacts);
    } else {
        echo "<p>Please enter the contacts</p>";
    }
?>

<form method="post" action="">
    <?php for($x = 0; $x < 100; $x++): ?>
    <input type="text" name="contacts[]" value="<?php echo (isset($contacts[$x])) ? $contacts[0] : ''; ?>"/>
    <?php endfor; ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

**Edit 2**

I have now made the form a loop, meaning it will create all our contact inputs for us. On top of this, if we have already posted the form each field will have the correct contact values.

If you are not aware of the syntax, `echo isset($contacts[$x])) ? $contacts[$x] : '';` is a `ternary operator` which is a one line `if/else` statement.

Which can also be tested here: http://phpfiddle.org/api/run/ugb-cta

Comment: I can't call the array. And says null on line 2 which is the $contacts  line

Comment: The `$_POST` array is only populated when you have submitted the form.

Comment: thanks, how can I save the array to make it become the value of the input

Comment: @srtstripes I've made another edit for you. Is this what you meant by "saving the value of the input"?

Answer (score 2):

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 101; $i++){
     ${"contact".$i}  = $_POST['contact'.$i];
     echo ${"contact".$i};
}
```

Comment: Says undefined index: contact0-contact101

Comment: @srtstripes I have checked but not getting any error. You just echo `$contact0`. It will show the exact value.

Comment: @srtstripes Can you please tell me your contact text box start with which name? `contact0` or `contact1`

Comment: @srtstripes plese show me the code where are you printing `$contact0`